# Pandas Dataframe column getting implicitly converted to Nan after merge

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

Below are small samples of my 2 pandas dataframe:

```
    In [65]: df1
 Out[65]:
          Send_Agent  Send_Amount Country_Code
 0     AWD120279        85.99          KW
 1     API185805        22.98          PH
 2     ANO080012       490.00          NO
 3     AUK359401       616.16          GB
 4     ACL000105       193.78          CL


 In [44]: df2
Out[44]:
Country_Code  Rating
0         KW Medium
1         PH Higher
2         NO Lower
3         GB Lower
4         CL Lower

In [97]: df4 = df1[df1['Send_Agent']=='AWD120279']

In [98]: df4
Out[98]:
 Send_Agent  Send_Amount Country_Code
0     AWD120279        85.99          KW
3359  AWD120279       200.00          KW
3878  AWD120279       203.03          KW

In [102]: df5 =  df2[df2['Country_Code']=='KW']
In [104]: df5
 Out[104]:
           Country_Code  Rating
  15           KW         Medium


    In [105]: pd.merge(df4,df5,on='Country_Code',how='left')
Out[105]:
Send_Agent  Send_Amount Country_Code Rating
0  AWD120279        85.99          KW     NaN
1  AWD120279       200.00          KW     NaN
2  AWD120279       203.03          KW     NaN
```

I am not able to figure out why the 'Rating' column getting converted to Nan after the merge. Every Country_Code has a rating associated with it. So , it should never be Nan.

Comment: your sample data does not show any overlap of countries.

Comment: Just added them now. but I did mention there that every country does have a rating and this is only a sample.

Comment: I ran this and for every country that had a corresponding row in `df2` I saw `'Rating'` populated correctly.  Confirmed again.

Comment: Why don't you provide code that produces the dataframe instead of text of what the dataframe looks like.  Then test it yourself on the code you provide.  For example, `df2 = pd.DataFrame([['KW', 'Medium']], columns=['Country_Code', 'Rating'])`

Comment: @piRSquared please see the edited question. Commenting here with a larger piece of code sucks.